# How to authorise to MS Project ODATA API by using ClientCredentialFlow?

Tags: python, azure, odata, ms-project, azure-app-registration

I am using the Python msal package and the `ClientCredentialFlow` when trying to authenticate to the MS-project odata API using following script:

```py
import requests
import msal

def get_access_token():
    # Set your Azure AD tenant ID, client ID (Application ID), and client secret
    tenant_id = "your_tenant_id"
    client_id = "your_client_id"
    client_secret = "your_client_secret"

    # Create a confidential client application
    confidential_client = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        client_id,
        authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}",
        client_credential=client_secret
    )

    # Define the scope (permissions) you want to request
    scopes = ["https://your_tenant_name.sharepoint.com/.default"]  # Replace "your_tenant_name" with your actual tenant name

    # Get an access token using the "Client Credentials" flow
    result = confidential_client.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)

    if "access_token" in result:
        access_token = result["access_token"]
        return access_token
    else:
        print("Failed to obtain access token.")
        return None

def get_project_data():
    # Set the API endpoint URL
    ms_project_api_url = 'https://your_tenant_name.sharepoint.com/sites/your_project_instance/_api/ProjectData/'

    # Get the access token
    access_token = get_access_token()

    if access_token:
        # Create the headers with the access token
        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        # Make the API request
        response = requests.get(ms_project_api_url, headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            # The request was successful, you can process the response here
            print("Data successfully retrieved:")
            print(response.json())  # If the API returns JSON data
        else:
            # The request was not successful, display the error message
            print("Error while retrieving data. Status code:", response.status_code)
            print(response.text)
    else:
        print("Failed to obtain access token.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_project_data()
```

**Which scope do I need and what permissions are needed in the Appregistration via Azure?**

As far as I understood I need some application-permissions, but can't find some which belong to MS Project.
I just found following delegated permissions in SharePoint group: `Project.Read`, `Project.Write`, `ProjectWebApp.FullControl`, `ProjectWebAppReporting.Read` and tried them out:

[image: screenshot of delegated permissions in Appregistry]

I tried with different scopes, e.g.:
*["https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/.default"]*
here I got an access-token, but no access to the API, `get_project_data()` fails with:

> *The request was not valid or is malformed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, **client credentials** flow only works with permissions of **`Application`** type but they are not currently available for MS Project.

I registered one Azure AD application and added below **Delegated** API permissions by granting consent:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment, I too got **same error** as below:

```py
import requests
import msal

def get_access_token():
    # Set your Azure AD tenant ID, client ID (Application ID), and client secret
    tenant_id = "tenantID"
    client_id = "appID"
    client_secret = "secret"

    # Create a confidential client application
    confidential_client = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        client_id,
        authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}",
        client_credential=client_secret
    )

    # Define the scope (permissions) you want to request
    scopes = ["https://xxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/.default"]  # Replace "your_tenant_name" with your actual tenant name

    # Get an access token using the "Client Credentials" flow
    result = confidential_client.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)

    if "access_token" in result:
        access_token = result["access_token"]
        return access_token
    else:
        print("Failed to obtain access token.")
        return None

def get_project_data():
    # Set the API endpoint URL
    ms_project_api_url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/pwademosite/_api/ProjectData/'

    # Get the access token
    access_token = get_access_token()
    
    #print(access_token)

    if access_token:
        # Create the headers with the access token
        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        # Make the API request
        response = requests.get(ms_project_api_url, headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            # The request was successful, you can process the response here
            print("Data successfully retrieved:")
            print(response.json())  # If the API returns JSON data
        else:
            # The request was not successful, display the error message
            print("Error while retrieving data. Status code:", response.status_code)
            print(response.text)
    else:
        print("Failed to obtain access token.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_project_data()
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To authorize to MS Project ODATA API, you need to make use of
> **Delegated** flows like username password, interactive flows etc... that works with permissions of **`Delegated`** type.

In my case, I changed to **username password** flow for which below option should be **enabled**(wait for few minutes after enabling as there will be delay):

[image]

When I ran below modified code with username password flow, I got Project data **response** successfully:

```py
import requests
import msal

def get_access_token():
    # Set your Azure AD tenant ID, client ID (Application ID), and client secret
    tenant_id = "tenantID"
    client_id = "appID"
    username = "admin@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"

    # Create a public client application
    public_client = msal.PublicClientApplication(
        client_id,
        authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}",
    )

    # Define the scope (permissions) you want to request
    scopes = ["https://xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/.default"]  # Replace "your_tenant_name" with your actual tenant name

    # Get an access token using the "Username Password" flow
    result = public_client.acquire_token_by_username_password(
    username=username,
    password=password,
    scopes=scopes,
)

    if "access_token" in result:
        access_token = result["access_token"]
        return access_token
    else:
        print("Failed to obtain access token.")
        return None

def get_project_data():
    # Set the API endpoint URL
    ms_project_api_url = 'https://xxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/pwademosite/_api/ProjectData/'

    # Get the access token
    access_token = get_access_token()
    
    #print(access_token)

    if access_token:
        # Create the headers with the access token
        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        # Make the API request
        response = requests.get(ms_project_api_url, headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            # The request was successful, you can process the response here
            print("\nData successfully retrieved:\n")
            print(response.content)  
        else:
            # The request was not successful, display the error message
            print("Error while retrieving data. Status code:", response.status_code)
            print(response.text)
    else:
        print("Failed to obtain access token.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_project_data()
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much Sridevi!
The authentication process also works for the _api/ProjectServer/ endpoint, if someone searching for that stumbles upon this post :)